# C# WFA - increase value until limit then decrease loop

Tags: c#

I want to do a program in C# - WFA, in which while a button is pressed - the label 1 value is increased by 10 since it reaches 100, then in decreases to 0 and again is increased til 100
like: 0 10 20 30...80 90 100 90 80...20 10 0 10...

i tried this:

```
private static int i = 0;

protected void button1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (i < 100)
        i = i + 10;
    else
        i = i - 10;
       
    this.label1.Text = i.ToString();
}
```

but it just decrease from 100 to 90 and the increases back to 100 and goes like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save two state information about the current value outside the `button1_MouseClick()` method. One is the value `i`, which you already do. The other is the information if you are going up or down. You can save this in a simple `bool` value like:

```
public static bool goingUp=true;
```

Then you can use these two fields `i` and `goingUp` and decide what you want to do:

```
if (goingUp)
{
    i += 10;
    if (i >= 100)
    {
        goingUp = false;
    }
}
else
{
    i -= 10;
    if (i <= 0)
    {
        goingUp = true;
    }
}

this.label1.Text=i.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

an easy way would be this one

```
_indexValue = (_indexValue + 1) % 100;
```

and when it hits 100 then it restart to 0